# No response from AWS SES when I try to send an email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-php-sdk

I have a recent issue with my emails, on week ago I started get errors in my email sending, problem is that sometimes when I call this function `sendEmail` it never returns the `Aws/Result` or any `Exception`. So my script is looped waited for it. The issue is sporadic. I supposes that my requested couldn't be added to AWS queue but I would get an Exception at least.

I tried to find a timeout setting that I could set to don't eternally wait, but I couldn't find it in documentation. I have 2 years using this service and I haven't get error until now.

Somebody else has experienced this issue?

Where can I set a timeout for this calls related to SES Class?

Simple code:

```
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException;

// Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
// This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
define('SENDER', 'sender@example');

// Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account
// is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
define('RECIPIENT', 'recipient@example.com');

define('SUBJECT', 'Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for PHP)');

define('HTMLBODY', '<h1>AWS Amazon Simple Email Service Test Email</h1>' .
    '<p>This email was sent with <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/ses/">' .
    'Amazon SES</a> using the <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/">' .
    'AWS SDK for PHP</a>.</p>');
define('TEXTBODY', 'This email was send with Amazon SES using the AWS SDK for PHP.');

define('CHARSET', 'UTF-8');

$_AWSAPICredentials = array(
    'key' => 'AWSAPIKEY',
    'secret' => 'AWSAPISECRET',
);
$_AWSAPIVersion = 'latest';
$_AWSAPIRegion = 'us-west-2';

$_SES = new SesClient([
    'version' => $_AWSAPIVersion,
    'region' => $_AWSAPIRegion,
    'credentials' => $_AWSAPICredentials,
]);

$params = [
    'Destination' => [
        'ToAddresses' => [
            RECIPIENT,
        ],
    ],
    'Message' => [
        'Body' => [
            'Html' => [
                'Charset' => CHARSET,
                'Data' => HTMLBODY,
            ],
            'Text' => [
                'Charset' => CHARSET,
                'Data' => TEXTBODY,
            ],
        ],
        'Subject' => [
            'Charset' => CHARSET,
            'Data' => SUBJECT,
        ],
    ],
    'Source' => SENDER
];

try {
    $result = $_SES->sendEmail($params);
    $sMessageId = $result->get('MessageId');
} catch (SesException  $e) {
    print_r($e->getAwsErrorMessage());
}
```

Note: I'm using AWS SDK PHP version 3.67.20

When it fails, I'm getting this error

```
AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDo (truncated...)
 SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): Signature expired: 20181107T003842Z is now earlier than 20181107T005054Z (20181107T005554Z - 5 min.) - <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>Signature expired: 20181107T003842Z is now earlier than 20181107T005054Z (20181107T005554Z - 5 min.)</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-13bf5130fec1</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the solution.... I have synchronized NTP Time in my server and now it's working.
I let the link for Ubuntu SO that I followed
https://www.tecklyfe.com/fix-ubuntu-timedatectl-ntp-sync-no/

Maybe my machine's clock was at least sufficiently in sync that this error shouldn't came up every time.